# Como puedo hacer contendores encima de un slide?

Tags: html, css

Quiero saber como puedo hacer eso contenedores verdes pero como se ve en la imagen ya que estuve revisando el codigo pero creo que no encontre la clase la cual se esta utilizando para crear eso, pero segun veo eso contenedores (o no se como se le llamaria a eso)van encima del slider y he tratado de hacerlos pero no me queda igual... aqui la referencia [121cc.com](http://121cc.com)

[image: ejemplo de la sección deseada]

[image: ejemplo de la sección deseada 2 segundos después]

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código con el que estás trabajando? Ahora mismo es imposible saber a que te refieres sin poder reproducir tu problema.

Comment: solo tengo un slide basico amogo, pero para que me entiendas, esta aqui la pagina a la que quiero tomar referencia

Comment: http://www.121cc.com/

Comment: Postea tu código, si no es difícil ayudar. No vale solo con la referencia.

Comment: Alguien me podría decir, como se llama la textura que esta sobre la imagen (la que parecen rayas en diagonal) o si es un efecto de CSS

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola en esa página hay varios trucos entre los que destaco los siguientes:

- Hacemos los contenedores verdes laterales más pequeños mediante `margin-top: -1rem;`
- Los mandamos siempre abajo y a la izquierda con posicionamiento absoluto
- usamos `skewX` para deformar un div

```css
/*fuente de textos*/
body {
    font-family: Montserrat,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.7647058824em;
}

body {
    font-size: .9em;
}

body, label {
    font-weight: 400;
}

/*tamaño del video*/
.hero-block--video, .home .hero-block--video {
    height: calc(100vw / 1.7777778) !important;
    max-height: 75rem;
    background-position-y: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
/*manda el video al frente de la imágen cuando no carga*/
.home .hero-block--video {
    z-index: 1;
    background-position-x: 50%;
    background-position-y: 0;
    background-size: auto 75%;
}

/*manda los links abajo y los pone verdes*/
.hero-block__bottom-links {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #9fb937;
    width: 100%;
}

/*los pone uno tras otro horizontalmente*/
.hero-block__bottom-links .bottom-links__content {
    max-width: 92.5rem;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*quita linea de links*/
.btn:hover, .button:hover, .teaser-card.feature .teaser-card__link a:hover, .teaser-card.feature .teaser-card__link:hover, a, abbr[title], button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/*forma complementaria para formar el trapecio*/
.hero-block__bottom-link--feature::after, .hero-block__bottom-link--feature::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #7d922b;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}

/*orillas del trapecio*/
.hero-block__bottom-link--feature::after {
    right: -30px;
    transform: skewX(9deg);
}

.hero-block__bottom-link--feature::before {

    left: -30px;
    transform: skewX(-9deg);

}

/*cambia color de fondo del primer tab*/
.hero-block__bottom-link--feature {
    background-color: #7d922b;
}


/*mocha el alto de dos tabs*/
.hero-block__bottom-link {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.3333333333%;
    max-width: 33.3333333333%;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-top: -1rem;
    padding: .875rem 0.225rem 0rem;
    padding-right: 0.225rem;
    padding-left: 0.225rem;
}

/*orden de los textos*/
.hero-block__bottom-link--feature {
    position: relative;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}

/*orden de links*/
.hero-block__bottom-link:last-child {
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}

/*alineacion del texto gris*/
.hero-block__bottom-link {
    text-align: center;
}

/*color del texto superior de los tabs*/
.hero-block__bottom-link .bottom-link__heading {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/**color de texto inferior*/
.hero-block__bottom-link .bottom-link__subheading {
    color: #3a4314;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.125em;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-size: cover; background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 50% 50%; background-image: none;"><video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: visible; opacity: 1; width: auto; height: 722px;"><source src="https://121cc.com/assets/video/header.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>

<div class="hero-block__wrapper ">
  <!-- end -->



  <div class="hero-block__bottom-links">
    <div class="bottom-links__content">
      <div class="hero-block__bottom-link hero-block__bottom-link--feature">
        <a href="http://121cc.com/visit">
          <span class="bottom-link__heading">Visit Us</span>
          <span class="bottom-link__subheading">What To Expect, Service Times &amp; Directions</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="hero-block__bottom-link ">
        <a href="http://121cc.com/next-steps">
          <span class="bottom-link__heading">Next Steps</span>
          <span class="bottom-link__subheading">Get Involved at 121</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="hero-block__bottom-link ">
        <a href="http://121cc.com/ministries/mission/serve">
          <span class="bottom-link__heading">Serve</span>
          <span class="bottom-link__subheading">Impact The Community</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Propiedad z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) tal vez es a lo que te refieres, superponer contenedores en otros:

ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo Propiedad z-index]